# How do you test nested methods in a React component in an Enzyme test?

Tags: reactjs, testing, sinon, enzyme

I've got the following function set as an onClick in a React component:

```
firstFunction = (id) => {
    this.props.secondFunction(id);      
}
```

I would like to be able to test that the first function is clicked, and then that the second function is clicked. I can test that the second function is invoked with the following test, which will pass:

```
describe('events can be invoked', () => {
    it('has a onClick event that can be called', () => {
        let mockFirstInvocation = sinon.spy();
        let mockSecondInvocation = sinon.spy();
        let wrapper = shallow(<ButtonOpt onClick={mockFirstInvocation} secondFunction={mockSecondInvocation}) 
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); 
        expect(mockSecondInvocation.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    })
});
```

However, if I add this line:

```
expect(mockFirstInvocation.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```

and it is placed before the expect for the mockSecondInvocation, the test fails.

How do you test that both the function called, and its nested function are both invoked explicitly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Testing the second function can be done with the following line of code.

```
wrapper.prop('secondFunction')(() => {  console.log('test');  }); expect(handleClickStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```